# 404 error calling GET API from a shopify theme-extension

Tags: express, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm new to shopify development, and can't figure out how to call an authenticated API from a shopify theme-extension. Essentially, I'm trying to make a theme extension, where one of the functionalities is that when a checkbox is clicked, an API that counts the number of products is called.

I have a working api that gets the product count, and in `web>index.js`, I have set-up the end-point:

```
app.get("/api/products/count", async (_req, res) => {
  const countData = await shopify.api.rest.Product.count({
    session: res.locals.shopify.session,
  });
  res.status(200).send(countData);
});
```

Under `web>frontend>hooks`, I have the authenticated hooks set-up as shown below. I've tested that if I call the "api/products/count" API from one of the web pages using `useAppQuery`, it works as expected, and returns the product count.

```
import { useAuthenticatedFetch } from "./useAuthenticatedFetch";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export const useAppQuery = ({ url, fetchInit = {}, reactQueryOptions }) => {
  const authenticatedFetch = useAuthenticatedFetch();
  const fetch = useMemo(() => {
    return async () => {
      const response = await authenticatedFetch(url, fetchInit);
      return response.json();
    };
  }, [url, JSON.stringify(fetchInit)]);

  return useQuery(url, fetch, {
    ...reactQueryOptions,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
};
```

In my theme extension code, I've added an event listener to the checkbox which calls getProductCount. In `getProductCount`, I want to call /api/products/count:

```
import { useAppQuery } from "../../../web/frontend/hooks";

export const getProductCount = (product) => {
  const {
    data,
    refetch: refetchProductCount,
    isLoading: isLoadingCount,
    isRefetching: isRefetchingCount,
  } = useAppQuery({
    url: "/api/products/count",
    reactQueryOptions: {
      onSuccess: () => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      },
    },
  });
}
```

However, when I run locally and click the checkbox, it returns a 404 error trying to find `useAppQuery`. The request URL is https://cdn.shopify.com/web/frontend/hooks. It seems like the authentication isn't working because that URL looks incorrect.

Am I missing a step that I need to do in order to call an authenticated API from a theme-extension?

I thought the issue was just the import path for `useAppQuery` but I've tried different paths, and they all return the same 404 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a hot tip here. In your theme App extension, you do not actually need to make an API call to get a product count. In your theme app extension, you can just use Liquid, and dump the product count out to a variable of your choice, and use the count, display the count, do whatever.

```
{{ shop.product_count }}
```

Of course, this does not help you if you need other storefront API calls in your theme App extension, but whatever. In my experience, I render the API Access Token I need in my theme app extension, and then making my Storefront API calls is just a fetch().

The only time I would use authenticated fetch, is when I am doing embedded App API calls, but that is a different beast from a theme app extension. In there, you do not get to make authenticated calls as the front-end is verboten for those of course. Instead you'd use App Proxy for security.

TL:DR; Storefront API calls with a token should not fail with a 404 if you call the right endpoint. You can use Storefront API inside a theme app extension. Inside a theme app extension, if you need backend Admin API access, you can use App Proxy calls.

Comment: Thanks David! shop.product_count does what I need!